# How to Free Memory of A Structure with Pointers to another Structure

Tags: c, memory, free

I have two structures

```
struct SimpleXY
{
    double x;
    double y;

};

    struct SimpleXyLink
    {
            int num_xy;
            SimpleXY *simpleXyList;
    };
```

I wonder what is the proper way to free the memory hold by `SimplyXyLink`? I am currently using

```
void Free(SimpleXyLink *myList)
{

    free(myList->simpleXyList);
}
```

But I think this is wrong because it doesn't free the memory inside the element of `simpleXyList`.

Comment: You tagged this `c++` but are using `free` (and presumably `malloc`) did you mean to tag this `c` instead?

Comment: @KitsuneTYMG, I think either one is OK. But anyway, I've changed the tag to `c`

Comment: Well as you can see from the answers, if you tag it `c++` and use `free` people are going to be confused about want you want. While `free` works fine in c++ compilers, the way to allocate in c++ is `new`

Answer (score 5):

First, the memory you're not freeing is the SimpleXy**Link** `myList`, not the memory inside the simpleXyList (you're freeing the memory referred to by that just fine).

In general, it's up to you to figure out a way to free all the memory you're using. In general, you'll free the referred-to data before the structure that refers to it, as in:

```
void FreeSimpleXy(SimpleXyLink *myList) {
    free(myList->simpleXyList);
    free(myList);
}
```

Note (C++ only), however, that if you used `new` to allocate these, you **must** use delete to free instead!

If you're using C++, there's also more foolproof ways. First, destructors. You could change `SimpleXyLink` like so:

```
struct SimpleXyLink
{
    int num_xy;
    SimpleXY *simpleXyList;
    ~SimpleXyLink() {
        delete simpleXyList;
    }
    SimpleXyLink() {
        simpleXyList = NULL; // run when object is created with new
    }
};
```

Now you can just do `delete someLink;` and it will free the contained simpleXyList automatically. **However**, keep in mind that you **must not** use `malloc` and `free` now - use `new` and `delete` instead:

```
SimpleXyLink *link = new SimpleXyLink;
link->simpleXyList = new SimpleXYList;
delete link; // all gone!
```

Finally, there's one more almost-magical way of doing things - using smart pointers (also C++ only). These will be added to the next version of C++, but you can use them today by using the [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

```
struct SimpleXyLink {
    int num_xy;
    boost::scoped_ptr<SimpleXyList> simpleXyList; // or shared_ptr
};
```

These will eliminate the need to write a destructor (you still must use `new` and `delete` however!), but they carry with them other restrictions as well. Read the documentation I linked carefully before using, and feel free to open another question if you're still not sure.

Comment: smart pointers-- interesting! But is it just garbage collector in action, and hence will it inherit all the garbage collector's problem?

Comment: @Graviton C++ does not have a garbage collector.

Comment: Smart pointers just automate the destructor technique I showed you - when a struct is destructed, the destructors for all (_non-pointer_) members are called as well. The `scoped_ptr` destructor then deletes the pointer hidden inside the `scoped_ptr`. Incidentally, there _are_ in fact garbage collectors for C++ (eg http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) - but they tend to not perform as well as in other languages that are designed to give more useful information to the GC.

Comment: Why is it recommended to do `simpleXyList = NULL; // run when object is created with new`?

Answer (score 2):

If it is C++ (I'm confused here because you use free :-))

```
struct SimpleXY
{
    double x;
    double y;

};

struct SimpleXyLink
{   
    SimpleXyLink() : simpleXyList( new SimpleXY ) { }
    ~SimpleXyLink() { delete simpleXyList; }

    int num_xy;
    SimpleXY *simpleXyList;
};

int main() 
{
    SimpleXyLink* pXYLink = new SimpleXyLink();

    delete pXYLink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on how you allocated the memory. Freeing memory always has to echo the allocation.

That said, `free` is almost certainly wrong in C++. Use `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free`.

Furthermore, it seems as though you’re allocating memory for several elements her (at least the name `…List` implies this) so you will probably be better off using a C++ container structure, such as `vector` or `list`.