# Free Memory of A Structure with two Data Fields

Tags: c

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680817/how-to-free-memory-of-a-structure-with-pointers-to-another-structure).

I have the following structure:

```
struct SimpleXY
{
    double x;
    double y;

};

struct SimpleEdge
{
   SimpleXY first;
   SimpleXY second;
}

    struct SimpleEdgeList
    {
            uint num_edges;
            SimpleEdge *SimpleEdges;
    };
```

What is the proper way to free the memory hold by `SimpleEdgeList`?  This is my current approach, but I wonder whether I should manually free `first` and `second` data field or not.

```
void Free(SimpleEdgeList *myList)
{

    free(myList->SimpleEdges);
}
```

This is a C structure and I'm looking for a C like memory releasing.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a linked list implementation? If so, you should be doing `struct SimpleEdgeList { int num_xy; SimpleEdgeList *next; };`, and the `Free()` function will be a little bit more involved.

Comment: Having a `struct` with a member of the same name is very confusing. Please don't do that.

Comment: @Chris, it is *not* a link list. My structure is correct. But I edit the member name for clarification

Comment: Alright. As a follow up question based on your clarified names, is `num_xy` the number of items allocated in `SimpleEdges` ? If this is the case, it should be a `size_t`, which is an unsigned type (you don't want to try to make an array of -1 items.)

Comment: @Chris, I've done further editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to manually free the fields.  When you free the memory referenced by `myList->SimpleEdgeList`, the call to `free()` will clean up the entire block of memory, including the two fields you mentioned.  Since those fields don't contain pointers to any other objects, you don't need to descend into them to reclaim memory.

Answer (score 4):

Your current approach is fine.

The simple rule is this: exactly one `free()` is required for each `malloc()`.  Since you have just one `malloc()`, you need just one `free()`.